# Trying to get 4 columns with masonry, whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

On this page: http://dev1.tigerweb.dk/YTcapture/features/brands I try to get 4 columns grid, but it doesnt work. Whats wrong?

I have tried many methods, and now i am using the method described at masonry's homepage with an element inside the container giving the width of columns.

```
<script src="http://dev1.tigerweb.dk/YTcapture/tigerweb/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script><script src="http://dev1.tigerweb.dk/YTcapture/tigerweb/image.js"></script><style>
.grid-sizer {width:25%;}
.masonry-item {
width: 25%; 
padding:15px;
background:#e0e0e0;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.masonry-item.w2 { width: 25%; }
</style>
<div style="position: relative; height: 1206px;" id="container">
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item" ><h2 class="uk-article-title" style="font-size: 36px;margin-bottom:0px;">Brands Tiles</h2>Aalborg eller Ålborg[3] er en by i Region Nordjylland</div>
  <div class="masonry-item w2"><h2 class="uk-article-title" style="font-size: 36px;margin-bottom:0px;">Brands Tiles</h2>Aalborg eller Ålborg[3] er en by i Region Nordjylland</div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><h2 class="uk-article-title" style="font-size: 36px;margin-bottom:0px;">Brands Tiles</h2>Byens navn kendes som Alabur og Alebu på mønter fra 1000-tallet. I Kong Valdemars Jordebog hedder den Aleburgh. Navnet menes at komme af áll, der er en smal strøm eller sejlrende.</div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><h2 class="uk-article-title" style="font-size: 36px;margin-bottom:0px;">Brands Tiles</h2>Stavemåden med Å blev indført efter retskrivningsreformen i 1948. Undervisningsminister Bertel Haarder og kulturminister Mimi Jacobsen bestemte i 1984, at kommunerne selv kunne vælge stavemåde.</div></div><script>
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
  gutter: 10
});
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
  msnry.layout();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest replacing the content of the script tag at the bottom with:

```
var wall = new Masonry(document.querySelector("#container"),{columnWidth: 20, isFitWidth: true});
wall.reloadItems();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TbZZ/) or it didn't happen!